# WordPress stripping away backslashes from HTML

Tags: plugins, escaping

Hi I'm kind of new to WordPress. I have come across this issue lately when running my webpages from my WordPress server.

I have this piece of code that clears any white spaces in the text input field. But after uploading it to the server directory, the backslashes in that peice of code is stripped away. The same happens to js file as well. Due to this I'm unable to use the js `\n` character at all.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input#MobileNo").on({
  keydown: function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32)
      return false;
  },
  change: function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
   }
 });

 });
</script>
```

Any idea how to fix this. I have read that `esc_js()` can be used, but don't know how.

WordPress is great and secure and hence I want to learn it.

Comment: Just answered your question on `esc_js()`. Can you elaborate on what you were trying to achieve with your JavaScript code above? Are all your concerns captured in my response below?

Comment: The JavaScript code mentioned above, is in the HTML code. The function of the code is to remove whitespaces a in a input field. But when the file is uploaded to the WordPress server, the `this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");` gets changed to `this.value = this.value.replace(/s/g, "");` ... Due to this the code does not work. So if I have to use `esc_js()`, whats the syntax in this situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[`esc_js()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_js/) is used to escape single quotes, htmlspecialchar " < > &, and fix line endings; it takes only a single required parameter as a string: the *text to be escaped*, and returns an escaped text.

It is intended to be used for inline JavaScript such as the `onclick=""` attribute (note that the strings have to be in [single quotes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/javascript/#strings)). The [`'js_escape'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/js_escape/) filter is also applied here.

In practice, using the `esc_js()` function is quite simple and is encouraged for [sanity of data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

Let's take a look at its usage in the example below;

Instead of simply echoing a variable as in `<?php echo $variable; ?>` for an `onclick=""` attribute when using inline JavaScript, you should leverage on the `esc_js()` function and as such, you should instead do this: `<?php echo esc_js( $variable ); ?>`.

So: use (good)

```
<a href="/news/" onclick="alert( '<?php echo esc_js( $variable ); ?>' )"></a>
```

instead of (bad)

```
<a href="/news/" onclick="alert( '<?php echo $variable; ?>' )"></a>
```

---

*Introduced in version [2.8.0](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/since/2.8.0/) and defined in [wp-includes/formatting.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3895), the `esc_js()` related Functions include: [`esc_sql()`](https://wpseek.com/function/esc_sql/), [`esc_url()`](https://wpseek.com/function/esc_url/), [`esc_html()`](https://wpseek.com/function/esc_html/), [`esc_attr()`](https://wpseek.com/function/esc_attr/), [`fetch_rss()`](https://wpseek.com/function/fetch_rss/).*